# Что значит термин "поток выполнения"?

Tags: многопоточность, терминология

Только что начал изучение многопоточного программирования. Судя по тому, что я сейчас прочитал, я записал себе такое определение:

Поток выполнения (thread - нить) - наименьшая единица обработки, которая содержит определённые сведения об обрабатываемом коде и в итоге реализует его. Процесс исполнения программы состоит в одних случаях - из одного потока, в других случаях - из нескольких потоков. Многопоточность позволяет процессору выполнять несколько потоков, что обеспечивает их параллельную работу и часто экономию ресурсов. Т.е, один поток будет выполнять программу по заданной последовательности, а несколько могут "разделать этот код по частям", тем самым, каждый поток получит свои сведения и задачи и в итоге задачи будут разделены и их параллельное выполнение будет быстрее, чем однопоточное.

Правильно ли я написал определение термина? Если нет, прошу подправить

Answer (score 0):

Да

> тем самым, каждый поток получит свои сведения и задачи и в итоге задачи будут разделены и их параллельное выполнение будет быстрее, чем однопоточное.

Не совсем верно, в общем случае быстрее выполняется, но может уперется в то что потокам нужен определенный ресурс и они будут "сражаться" за него

Answer (score 0):

я бы не сказал что это наименьшая единица обработки. Такое определение можно и к функции применить и к процессу.

Поток это объект операционной системы, выполняемый одновременно с другими потоками в рамках одного процесса. по сравнению с процессом он более легковесный (у него нет отдельной от процесса памяти и других ресурсов ОС (файлы, сокеты и т.п.)), по сравнению в горутинами какими-нить - более тяжеловесный.

Чтобы разделить последовательный код для выполнения на нескольких потоках, надо его переделать, сам код автоматически не разделится для выполнения по частям в разных потоках. Ну тоесть это задача программиста, написать эффективный многопоточный код, который с одной стороны, утилизирует больше ядер процессора, и сделает таким образом обработку быстрее, и будет корректно обрабатывать данные с другой стороны. Это зависит от задачи и обрабатываемых данных.

Обычно многопоточность используется в системах обработки каких-то относительно независимых друг от друга запросов, наример, веб-сервер, который обрабатывает запросы от разных пользователей одновременно на разны потоках. Это эффективнее, по сравнению с обработкой каждого запроса в отдельном процессе ОС (хотя когда-то давно на заре веба применялось и такое).